# Want different tables rows in new rows

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 10 tables in my db for logs data. I want to fetch data from all of them with some conditions like order by. These tables have a common column ORDERID in them.

For example:-
Table 1 -: ORDER_AREA_1

```
RECID         ORDERID        ORDER TO  
  1           A1_001           JIM  
  2           A1_002           SAM  
  3           A1_003           TIM
```

Table 2 -: ORDER_AREA_2

```
RECID         ORDERID        ORDER TO  
  1           A2_001          ALBERT  
  2           A2_002           JOHN  
  3           A2_003          KEVEN
```

Table 3 -: ORDER_AREA_3

```
RECID         ORDERID        ORDER TO  
  1           A3_001          SPENCER  
  2           A3_002          CRISTY  
  3           A3_003           JOE
```

Now I want the result to be as

```
ORDERID        ORDER TO  
A1_001           JIM  
A1_002           SAM  
A1_003           TIM
A2_001          ALBERT  
A2_002           JOHN  
A2_003          KEVEN
A3_001          SPENCER  
A3_002          CRISTY  
A3_003           JOE
```

I want a query that will result in this manner.
Please help with this.

Answer (score 2):

```
select ORDERID,`ORDER TO` from ORDER_AREA_1
union all
select ORDERID,`ORDER TO` from ORDER_AREA_2
union all
select ORDERID,`ORDER TO` from ORDER_AREA_3
```

Comment: but how I will put the conditions like order by

Comment: you mean the final data order by ?

Comment: yes.. and i got it. But can there be any other way in which these multiple selects queries may be run, only a single select query may work.

Comment: no you have to do union since its merging data from different tables into one. Its not even joining where you join tables with a common key and get the data.

Comment: This seems to be a good answer; if it helped you can I suggest you accept it?